# echo "" | sudo -S as an alternative to sudo -n

Tags: sudo

I'm on Debian Lenny. Unfortunately, the factory sudo package is not including the -n option that ships with sudo version 1.7. I'd really like to have a way to specify "If sudo asks for a password, I prefer to fail immediately instead of hanging on a prompt". Will this alternative work?

```
echo "" | sudo -S -u lalala command
```

Answer (score 2):

This will only work with certain commands.  When it needs a password, sudo will fail as expected, in a somewhat ugly fashion.  When it doesn't, however, the newline will be piped to the command that you're running with sudo.

cat works fine:

```
cacheson@segfault:~$ echo "" | sudo -S -u cacheson cat file.txt 
text file
```

vim does not:

```
cacheson@segfault:~$ echo "" | sudo -S -u cacheson vim file.txt 
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Vim: Finished.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your command will end up reading from standard input as well (as [Chris Acheson](https://superuser.com/questions/310203/echo-sudo-s-as-an-alternative-to-sudo-n/310265#310265)). You'd better redirect standard input back from the terminal.

```
echo | sudo -S -u lalala sh -c 'command </dev/tty'
```